# Displaying what leads did in a product in the CRM

Tags: rest-api

I have built a product that tracks leads as they move around the product, similar to a website where visitors can view different pieces information. I want to be able to add what information they look at under their lead object into salesforce.

Along the lines of:

- Lead has looked at pricing page and also looked at the request demo page.

**What i have tried**

1. I have seen some people do this with campaigns and campaign status but this doesn't fulfil my requirement of clicking on a lead and seeing everything the lead has looked at.
2. Another thing I tried was to log lead events but this will fill the users calendar with these "pageview"-esque events instead of their meetings.

Any suggestions?

**I ended up creating a custom object**

I ended up creating a custom object through the website. I now need to figure out how to do this programmatically so when a new users links my product/app with their own salesforce the custom object/fields and tabs get setup correctly

Comment: Look at the Cookie Class in Apex or Visualforce Dev Guide.

Comment: whats the cookie class got to do with displaying lead contents in the CRM?

Comment: I would probably create a custom object that has a lookup or Master-Detail relationship with leads and create these records for your page views.

Comment: who are the "users"? the Lead owner? or the customer prospect interacting with your external website?

Comment: yes the lead owner, the sales rep who logs into sf to view the leads

Comment: So you're basically asking us what would make most sense to store this info as ? Updating your question to be more specific and taking the right tags may hel p you get an answer.

Comment: what tags should i have included? i was posting content through the rest api for the CRM product